# Gtk Switch activate signal not firing

Tags: events, gtk, pygobject, gobject

I'm trying to use a Gtk.Switch widget in an app but "activate" signal is not firing by clicks. 
It works fine when using the widget with keyboard by hitting reture/space key on it but clicks don't fire the "activate" event.

Any Idea what is to be done in order to register signals for clicks on Gtk.Switch

```
from gi.repository impoty Gtk, GObject

def my_callback(widget, data=None):
    print 'Event Fired'

switch = Gtk.Switch()
window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(switch)
switch.connect('activate', my_callback)
window.show_all()
GObject.MainLoop().run()
```

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with PyGTK, but with GObject. PyGTK is for GTK 2.X.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, a better way is connect to the notify::active event.

Comment: The benefit of using this rather than the "button-press-event" is it will work correctly if the switch is toggled via another method e.g. key press / accessibility framework.

Comment: yes, I agree. Make it switch.connect('notify::active', my_callback) for python

Comment: Note to glade user: I spent a long time figuring how to register a handler for "listen::active", so this might be useful for other glade users. If you're using glade, you'll notice that there does not seem to be "notify::active" in the signals list, this is because it's a GObject signal "listen", use the "Detail" column to add the second parameter "active" to register a handler for "listen::active".

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after looking around for a couple of days I asked the question here and found the answer 5 minutes later.

To register mouse click, 'button-press-event' signal has to be used instead of 'activate' signal.

Might help someone with a similar problem.

GTK needs better documentation.

Comment: Submit a patch on bugzilla.gnome.org to improve this particular lapse in the documentation! ;-)

Comment: -1 Usually, you shouldn't rely on concrete input methods unless you're making your own component. I think what you want to do is being notified when the switch **changes its state** (via the keyboard, dragging, ...), not when the user clicks with his mouse. **See Kknd's answer instead.**